# Android : Check phone number present in Contact List ? (Phone number retrieve from phone call)

Tags: android, contacts, broadcastreceiver

I make a `BroadcastReceiver` to receive Phone number of the person who call me

```xml
<intent-filter>
<action
    android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
</intent-filter>
```

1. How to check if the phone number receive is on my contact list ?
   Do you have a tip to know if this phone number exist on contact list with out loading contact list ?
   I don't want more information, just if this phone number exist.
2. If it's not possible, and I must load contact list, how to do it on `BroadcastReceiver` ?
   When I try to do `getContentResolver`, it's not working because I'm on `BroadcastReceiver` and not inside `Activity`...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```java
public boolean contactExists(Context context, String number) {
    // number is the phone number
    Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
    String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { PhoneLookup._ID, PhoneLookup.NUMBER, PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };
    Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);
    try {
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            cur.close();
            return true;
        }
    } finally {
        if (cur != null)
            cur.close();
        }
   }

   return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried this code, and it works when I have the "exact" number, but depending on country code, other prefixes it doesn't always find the number, even when a number exists, and calling this number will call the same person (number in the contacts: 5556, number received: 15555215556)

Comment: unfortunately no

Answer (score 9):

I think it's important to say that you need to add the following in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Answer (score 3):

for 1 you should have a look at the recommended [ContactsContract.PhoneLookup](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html) provider

A table that represents the result of looking up a phone number, for example for caller ID. To perform a lookup you must append the number you want to find to CONTENT_FILTER_URI. This query is highly optimized.

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
Cursor mycursor=resolver.query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME,...
if (mycursor!=null && mycursor.moveToFirst()) {
// record exists
}
```

for 2 you can use the `context` from the onReceive method to call methods that belong to Context

```
ContentResolver cr=context.getContentResolver();
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use  `Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI` instead of `PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI`
because PhoneLookup can be empty and you will get no result from time to time (tested on LG-P500, froyo)

The problem on my device happens for example when:

1. switch to airplane mode
2. use the default message application to send a sms (will be queued).
3. use `PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI` to query for a contact

Not all devices seems to be affected

Using `PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI` the returned cursor is always empty.
Using `Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI` everything is ok (you find the contact if any).

Therefore I suggest you to always use `Phone.*` Uris except when you really need to use `PhoneLookup.*`... Which usually is just address book synchronization related stuff (and most of the times is not what you are interested in).